# What sampling rate to use when making IIR filters with an audio sample rate of 44.1kHz?

Tags: stm32, dsp, sampling, iir

I am kind of confused as to which sampling rate to use when making an IIR filter if the sampling rates for  audio are 44.41kHz, or 96kHz, etc..

**My concept and what has been working for me.** When people say it is sampling at 44.41kHz, it means the total sampling rate. So each channel is getting a sample rate of 44.41kHz*2 =~ 88820Hz

Example: If the audio was sampled at a rate of 92kHz then I would create an IIR filter using a Fs = 192kHz because each channel will be seeing 192kHz.

**The problem that caused me to re-think this:** I have an ESP32 being used as an audio sink that transfer audio samples at a rate of 44.41kHz into an STM32 that does the DSP.

I made a bandpass IIR filter using a sampling rate of ~= 88.820kHz and my audio sounds distorted when played. This is what I don't understand.

The audio sounds clean and nice when no DSP is being run.

Any suggestions?

Edit: To clarify I am using stereo for both examples.

UPDATE 1:

I have a post [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/527138/why-is-the-stm32-reference-manual-stating-the-wrong-sample-frequency-for-i2s) that we can further explain on what's happening, I am not sure why I am having a hard time grasping that stereo sampling right such as 44.41kHz is for each channel.

Here is my defence.

In the post above I have a DMA to trigger every 2 samples and each sample is L and R, using a WS = 48kHz

As you can see in the diagram at 4 samples the time is ~41.48uS.

To check how to see at what time it triggers at 2 samples (L + R) it will
2/(4/41.48us) take 20.74uS which is ~ 48kHz, this is why I believe the 48kHz, 96kHz is the sampling rate of both the L + R channel, and now to see 1 sample we do  1/(2/20.74uS) = 10.37uS which is = 96kHz

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

UPDATE 2: Based on everyone's comment I have alter the code to apply dsp to each channel separately and independently, however the issue still remains, the audio sounds very much distorted.

CODE:

```
int RxBuff_bluetooth[4];
int TxBuff_bluetooth[4];

    float inSample_bluetooth_L[2]; // Goes to RxBuff -> inSample
    float inSample_bluetooth_R[2];
    float outSample_bluetooth_L[2]; // Goes to outSamples -> TxBuff
    float outSample_bluetooth_R[2];
    
        void prcoess_bluetooth_halfSample(int * RxBuff_bluetooth, int * TxBuff_bluetooth, float * inSample_bluetooth_L, float * inSample_bluetooth_R, float * outSample_bluetooth_L, float * outSample_bluetooth_R, float scaleFactor, uint8_t volumeCurrent, arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 * audioStream_L, arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 * audioStream_R, float inputCompensator) {
        
                       for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++){
        
                          if (i % 2 == 0){ // L Samples
        
                          inSample_bluetooth_L[i] = (float) RxBuff_bluetooth[i] * (scaleFactor * (float) volumeCurrent) * inputCompensator;
        
                        } else if ( i % 2 == 1){ // R Samples
        
                          inSample_bluetooth_R[i-1] = (float) RxBuff_bluetooth[i] * (scaleFactor * (float) volumeCurrent) * inputCompensator;
        
                        }
                    }
                          arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(audioStream_L, inSample_bluetooth_L, outSample_bluetooth_L, 1);
                          arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(audioStream_R, inSample_bluetooth_R, outSample_bluetooth_R, 1);
        
                        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i ++){
        
                           if (i % 2 == 0) { // L Samples
        
                           TxBuff_bluetooth[i] = (int)outSample_bluetooth_L[i];
        
                         } else if ( i % 2 == 1) { // R Samples
        
                           TxBuff_bluetooth[i] = (int)outSample_bluetooth_R[i-1];
        
                         }
                    }
        }
        
        void prcoess_bluetooth_CompleteSample(int * RxBuff_bluetooth, int * TxBuff_bluetooth, float * inSample_bluetooth_L, float * inSample_bluetooth_R, float * outSample_bluetooth_L, float * outSample_bluetooth_R, float scaleFactor, uint8_t volumeCurrent, arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 * audioStream_L, arm_biquad_casd_df1_inst_f32 * audioStream_R, float inputCompensator) {
        
             for (int i = 2; i < 4; i ++){
        
                              if (i % 2 == 0){ // L Samples
        
                              inSample_bluetooth_L[i-1] = (float) RxBuff_bluetooth[i] * (scaleFactor * (float) volumeCurrent) * inputCompensator;
        
                            } else if ( i % 2 == 1){ // R Samples
        
                              inSample_bluetooth_R[i-2] = (float) RxBuff_bluetooth[i] * (scaleFactor * (float) volumeCurrent) * inputCompensator;
        
                            }
                        }
                              arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(audioStream_L, &inSample_bluetooth_L[1], &outSample_bluetooth_L[1], 1);
                              arm_biquad_cascade_df1_f32(audioStream_R, &inSample_bluetooth_R[1], &outSample_bluetooth_R[1], 1);
        
                            for (int i = 2; i < 4; i ++){
        
                               if (i % 2 == 0) { // L Samples
        
                               TxBuff_bluetooth[i] = (int)outSample_bluetooth_L[i-1];
        
                             } else if ( i % 2 == 1) { // R Samples
        
                               TxBuff_bluetooth[i] = (int)outSample_bluetooth_R[i-2];
        
                             }
                        }
        }
```

Comment: 44.1khz means 44100 samples per second. If stereo you have two independent streams of 44100 Hz. You do not have 88.2 KHz.

Comment: Yes its in stereo? Really I thought it mean total of 44100 samples per second? Can you please further explain this? I have measured this and some how I got both L and R being 44.41kHz and each being 88.2kHz, then why when using my inline sampling at 96kHz it doesnt work with IIR filters using the sampling rate of 96kHz but with 192kHz?

Comment: Read the original comment again.   Perhaps your attempts to measure the sample rate (a non-trivial task!) are flawed.  Correctly implementing filters without errors causing gross distortion is no small task.  It's often useful to make sure your algorithm uses portable width variables, and then to run it against test data in a build targeting your PC, to verify that you haven't made some sort of mistake in coding.  This is of course assuming that the straight through path is clean, and that the timing of the data interchange doesn't break when processing is attempted...

Comment: If the audio is sampled at 44.1 kHz, so is any normal filter. The exceptions are oversampling, and decimation (undersampling) which you probably don't need atthe moment.

Comment: This is blowing my mind , I’ll update the main post then maybe one of you guys explain to me what I am seeing then

Comment: @BrianDrummond updated the main post

Comment: @ChrisStratton Updated the main post, maybe you can explain to me now where I am wrong, based on my thinking

Comment: Your argument doesn't make any sense and is in conflict with how these things actually work.  44.1 KSPS stereo would be 44.1 K left samples and 44.1 K right samples.  Same for 48 KSPS.  You may be confusing yourself with misconfiguration of the DMA though. Look at the raw I2S or whatever it is waveform.  If you have a 44.1 or 48 Khz WS, that's your sample rate, high indicates one channels' data and low the other's.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, can you tell me where I am going wrong , can you maybe use the same picture in the post and show me how it’s suppose to be? In respect to the diagram is the logic correct? Cause then nothing makes sense to me anymore

Comment: Another reason what caused this confusion, I have another Audio codec setup as 24 bits 192 kHz stereo when I use the 192 kHZ iir filters doesn’t work, but when I use the 96 kHz they work fine, what’s going on then

Comment: @Leoc I just dropped in and haven't seen the progression of a discussion. But it appears to me that you are applying tools you don't understand well, except perhaps at a bird's eye view, and assuming plug-and-play works when the tools were not designed for such use but instead for people who understand what's going on under the hood.

Comment: @jonk you're probably right, thats why I invite anyone to show me the day or redirect me to useful material that can help me

Comment: @Leoc Since my understanding of what's going on in your head is limited to a cursory reading, my only "resonance" is asking you if you understand that the behavior of a digital filter instance changes when you change the data rate into and out of it. They are designed for specific rates. Change the rate and you change the filter behavior. Which means you must understand the entire chain and not just change things as you feel suits your mood. Unless, of course, you insert additional pieces (more than one) to compensate for rate changes.

Comment: Not sure how to respond back correctly, is yes I understand that changing the rate would in turn cause the filter behavior to change. I am just confused how the I2S bus is presented, with the post above in that picture it looks like what I described. The picture shows that every sample gets triggered at 96kHz , I hope you understand where I am coming from. If someone can show me an I2S bus and break it down maybe ill get it

Comment: Simply process each channel independently at 44.1 (or now it seems you have changed to 48) kHz.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'samples per second' with two different but related meanings. Make sure you know which is which in each context.

There's the 'audio, DSP, let's design a filter' context.

If you have 44.1 kS/s audio, whether you have one channel, stereo, or 24-track, each audio signal is sampled at 44100 times per second. A filter will be designed to run at 44.1 kS/s, and have its coefficients designed to provide the effects you want at that sample rate. If you have two channels, then you'd implement two filters, and run one on each channel. The best way to think of a stereo signal is that you still have 44.1 kS/s, where a 'sample' is now a stereo sample, consisting of two mono samples.

Then there's the 'computing hardware, let's hook up several ICs together' context.

An I2S link is physically a single channel. If these 44.1 k stereo samples are going to get pushed across a link, then physically 88.2 k mono samples get sent across the link. But this is an implementation detail, it's still conceptually 44.1 k stereo samples being sent across two logical links, one for each channel. Whether you need to program the hardware as 88.2 x 1, or 44.1 x 2, may differ between manufacturers.

Comment: I really appreciate the break down, the part where you said "If you have two channels, then you'd implement two filters, and run one on each channel" Can you still use one filter and just have it run on each channel?

Comment: You may be able to use one physical filter, but you must still have two logical filters, which will mean two physical stores of state, to get switched. You have left state, and right state. Run the left channel with left state, run the right channel with right state.

Comment: I mean, for example if you know the buffer gets filled with LRLRLR, and you run a filter from 0 .... to buffer[size] you can use one filter no? because the filter is evaluating each index so the output of the new buffer will be L* R*L*R* , *= its been filtered

Comment: @Leoc That might be designed as a clever implementation of two, logical, filters. Packing LR samples is a common way of implementing stereo. However, the filter will need to be designed as a stereo filter. That means under the hood, it's two mono filters run in parallel, so each filter takes samples from the input buffer in strides of 2, and each filter has its own state. They can share coefficients and code though. But going straight into running a special purpose stereo filter is going to confuse you, start with two mono filters in parallel. How does silence on one channel gets handled?

Comment: Interesting cause I got a 192kHz stereo audio stream working with using a IIR filter using a sample rate of 96kHz just one of it. What do you mean silence on one channel ? Just sounds like I have to re-do my dsp functions now

Comment: @Leoc A filter holds a history of its previous input samples, its 'state', and they go on to influence the output of that filter. Now the left output should only be influenced by the left history. This means that even if you have one call to a stereo filter routine, and feed it LRLR samples, internally it should treat L and R logically separately. BY silence on one channel, I mean let all R samples be zero, and they should be zero when they come out of the filter. That makes it easy to see whether you have any crossover between L and R samples.

Comment: I see what you mean, when you are sending back to the DAC you would format the buffer as LRLRLR still right? Because what would that mean I need to make two new buffers for L and one for R and run the DSP on them I guess

Comment: Okay, It just hit me now. I know exactly what you mean, yes the L and R DSP should be decoupled assuming the L and R are not the same audio signal

Comment: Just updated the main post and updated the code in what you suggested. Its still not working. Audio still sounds very distorted

Comment: @Leoc Have you tried the code with a unity filter, that simply returns output = input. That will establish whether you're calling correctly in a suitable sequence, and whether you're accidently changing the gain causing overloads. 'Audio distorted' is not a thorough problem description, what is it actually doing in terms of L and R input samples to L and R output samples, gain, ordering etc?

Comment: I figured out the problem, it was simply a misconfiguration of the I2S bus. I am using a dac that accepts a 24 bit data packet, I was sending 16 bits to the dac. When I changed the data len to 32 bits in the I2S reg everything sounds crisp now.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, not entirely sure why it works, but here it is.

[image]

Initially "CHLEN" = 16bit Wide and "DATLEN" = 16-bit data length

which I thought it was right as the ESP32 bluetooth I2S transfer 16 bits of data however changing both registers, "CHLEN" and "DATLEN" = 32bit it worked.

UPDATE: I believe the issue thrived from the hardware I am using, I have the ESP32 sending in 16bits however the DAC I'm using accepts 24bits, so it would make sense to set the hardware to 32bits as I was truncating bits before when setting the STM32 to accept/send 16bits.